# Progress bar is not being written continuously in ifort while it is in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have wrote a genetic algorithm in Fortran to be able to compute with a long double precision a generic fitness function. The first version (double precision) was written for gfortran where I implemented a progress bar.

Now I have to compile with ifort because gfortran is not capable of performing `real*16` calculations. All works fine but in this case (ifort) the progress bar does not work properly. Namely, only when the whole cycle is completed the progress bar is printed to std output.

Here is the piece of code for the progress bar:

```
if (rate(i).gt.ratemax) then

ratemax=rate(i)

write(*,"(1x,A57,D12.4,A27,f6.2,A1)",advance="no") &

'\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b ff: ', & 

ratemax,'             Progress:',100.*real(nmix)/real(nmixing),'%'

end if
```

I use an Intel Xeon of 64bit and the options for ifort are:

```
ifort -O2 -assume bscc FFevalLD.f90  func.o -o FFevalLD
```

while when use gfortran I compile in this way:

```
gfortran -ffree-form -O2 -fbackslash FFeval.f func.o -o FFeval
```

in gfortran (but double precision) all works fine.

Comment: solved:                        if (rate(i).gt.ratemax) then
                ratemax=rate(i)
1100    format(1x,A57,D12.4,A27,f6.2,A1,$)
                write(*,1100) &
                '\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$
                ratemax,'             Progress:',100.*real(nmix)/real(nmixing),'%'

Comment: If you solved it, then write your solution in an answer and accept it!

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757637/comparing-edit-descriptor-and-advance-no-in-fortran-output

Comment: I wouldn't expect gfortran of recent years to have a problem with REAL(REAL128).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
if (rate(i).gt.ratemax) then 
  ratemax=rate(i)
  1100 format(1x,A57,D12.4,A27,f6.2,A1,$) 
  write(*,1100) &
  '\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\‌​b\b\b\b\b\b\b$ ratemax,' Progress:',100.*real(nmix)/real(nmixing),'%'
```

Comment: It is always good to explain what does the code do. It was even pretty unreadable when put into a single line. Note that this (the `$` descriptor) will not compile in gfortran and it is not standard conforming.

Comment: Also, using a format string directly instead of the FORMAT statement, as the OP did, is the modern way to go.