# Comparing $ edit descriptor and advance="no" in Fortran output

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I know that the $ edit descriptor is not in the standard and that using `advance="no"` is recommended, but this little example shows that they have a different behaviour (with ifort but not with gfortran) and I don't understand why (it doesn't bother me more than that, but if anyone have an explanation I'm interested!).

```
program p
  use sleep_mod
  implicit none
  integer           :: i
  character(len=80) :: mymsg

  mymsg = 'H e l l o   w o r l d !  W e l c o m e - B i e n v e n u e - W i l l k o m m e n'
!
!- Write the characters of "mymsg" on the same line with a time delay between them:
!
  write(*,*)

  do i = 1, len_trim(mymsg)
     call usleep (onesec/4)
     write(*,'(a1,$)') mymsg(i:i)             ! ok w/ gfortran, ok w/ ifort
    ! write(*,'(a1)',advance='no') mymsg(i:i) ! ok w/ gfortran, KO w/ ifort
  end do

  write(*,'(/)')

end program p
```

The sleep_mod module is the following:

```
module sleep_mod
  use iso_c_binding

  integer(c_int32_t), parameter :: onesec = 100000_c_int32_t

  interface ! found in http://computer-programming-forum.com (by Tobias Burnu)
     subroutine usleep (useconds) bind(C)
       use iso_c_binding
       implicit none
       integer(c_int32_t), value :: useconds
     end subroutine
  end interface

end module sleep_mod
```

With the $ version, whatever is the compilator (ifort or gfortran) the result is as expected: a time delay between each character print. The same result is obtained with the version with `advance='no'` compiled with gfortran but not with ifort.

Comment: Oops, "preconised": a false friend ! I meant "recommended" by the standard.

Comment: May be the compiler does some optimisation, because it believes it does not change the result?

Comment: What compiler options are you using in each case?

Comment: My tests get the same behaviour in gfortran and in Intel. The one you desire. However I do get the long wait and the immediate print thereafter in Oracle Studio Fortran 12.6. 
 Which compiler version do you use? Which operating system? Which exact compiler flags?

Comment: Oh no, I was testing the other version. I suggest you uncomment the other line! So yes, I do get it for Intel as well and for Oracle even with `$`. A `flush` solves it for Oracle but very strangely not for Intel.

Comment: I am on mac OS 10.9.5 and I use: ifort 15.0.3 and  gfortran 6.3.0 with no particular option.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962009/progress-bar-gfortran-vs-ifort?rq=1